# Article Class: Why Default 10pt?

Tags: fontsize, article

A template I have created for doing work uses the article class with the `a4paper` and `11pt` options set. I have sometimes needed to use 10pt instead of 11pt for only *very* special circumstances. When I use the 10pt option, I can't decide whether to use 10pt as my default text size or not as it seems to read more easily but I can't decide whether or not if it actually does.

What I would like to know is why is the default font size for `article` 10pt? Is there any typographical reason why? Does it make it any easier to read?

NOTE: Using Standard Computer Modern font.

Comment: That depends very much on the font in use and on your personal taste. Usually I stick to 11 pt, mainly because with 10 pt, subscripts and subsubscripts look quite small.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your basic configuration. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and provide meaningful responses when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, I cannot tell from your question which fonts you are using in which formats. I don't know which engine you use or what packages you load which might be related.

Answer (score 0):

For personal notes, it's a matter of your taste.

However, if you are writing a paper for a journal, the specifications are up to the editorial board of the journal to decide... and they usually have manuals for users to follow.